# Help with LOAD DATA INTO FILE

Tags: php, mysql, database, load-data-infile

I have a database setup like

```
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ad-id` int(11) default NULL,
  `advertiser-id` int(11) default NULL,
  `advertiser-name` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `advertiser-category` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `buy-url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `catalog-id` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `currency` varchar(3) default NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `image-url` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `in-stock` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) default NULL,
  `manufacturer-name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `manufacturer-sku` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `retail-price` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `sale-price` decimal(10,2) default NULL,
  `sku` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `upc` varchar(50) default NULL,
```

I am trying to load the data like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE "/home/datafeed/tempfile.csv" REPLACE INTO TABLE products_import FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY """" LINES TERMINATED BY "\n" (ad-id, advertiser-id, advertiser-name, advertiser-category, buy-url,catalog-id,currency, description,image-url,in-stock,isbn,manufacturer-name,manufacturer-sku,name,price,retail-price,sale-price,sku, upc);
```

but it doesn't seem to like database names with dashes in them.  The field names are pretty much set in stone. If I try to insert without the field names it sets everything in the wrong field (starts with autoinc)

I'm not very good with MySQL any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put back-ticks around the field names: `ad-id`, etc., like in your table structure listing.

Comment: So simple! Why didn't I see that, Thanks!